# Update search filter with checkbox, VBScript asp

Tags: sql, checkbox, vbscript, hta

I have this dynamically search script made in a HTA showing all my notes.

I want to add a dynamic filter, based on two checkboxes that filters my SQL string in types: A, U and both (A or U).

When the script loads it runs perfectly and shows all notes with both types (A or U). But when I click the checkboxes I get an error saying: "Object doesn't support property or method" (translated from my language).

The script is fairly simple I think, but I cannot see the problem. The script `searchdata` is run dynamically through another script `count2` (onkeyup) . I wish the same thing for the checkboxes, so when the checkboxes are ticked, the corresponding results are shown immediately.

Hope I have made myself clear and thanks!

**VBScript containing the search filter**

```
sub searchdata
        If acheck.Checked = True AND ucheck.Checked = False Then
        Chkboxval = "A"
        End If
        If acheck.Checked = False AND ucheck.Checked = True Then
        Chkboxval = "U"
        End If
        If acheck.Checked = True AND ucheck.Checked = True Then
        Chkboxval = "U' OR Type='A"
        End If
        If acheck.Checked = False AND ucheck.Checked = False Then
        MsgBox ("Select a filter")
        End If
        SQL_query = "SELECT * FROM arbejde WHERE Title LIKE '%"& txtsrch.value &"%' AND Type='" & Chkboxval & "' ORDER BY Title"
        Set rsData = conn.Execute(SQL_query)
        strHTML2 = strHTML2 & "<table class='detail' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' id='detail' border=0 width='97%'><col style='width: 60%;'><col style='width: 31%;'><col style='width: 9%;'><thead><tr><th colspan='4' align='left'></th></tr></thead>"
        If rsData.EOF = True Then
        strHTML2 = strHTML2 & "<span style='color: red'>Ingen resultater!</span><br><a onClick='addNotat()' style='cursor: hand'>Klik her for at oprette et nyt notat</a>"
        End If
        Do Until rsData.EOF = True
        If (rsData("Length") <> "") Then
        infopic = "info-on"
        infolink = "onclick=window.open('" & rsData("Length") & "')"
        ELSE
        infopic = "info-off"
        infolink = ""
        End IF
        strHTML2 = strHTML2 & "<tbody id='bodytext'><tr class='parent' id='trparent' style='font-weight: bold;'><td id='title' height='21'>" & rsData("Title") & "</td><td id='kategori'>" & rsData("Cat") & " (" & rsData("Type") & ")</td><td align='right' id='tools'><img src='images/icons/"& infopic & ".png' width='13' height='13' title='Gå til forretningsgangen' "& infolink & "> <img src='images/icons/edit1.png' width='13' height='13' title='Rediger' onclick='editUser("& rsData("ID") &")' language='vbscript'> <img src='images/icons/slet1.png' width='13' height='13' onclick='deleteUser("& rsData("ID") &")' title='Slet' language='vbscript'>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr class='child'><td colspan='5' id='notat' height='21'>" & rsData("Notes") & "</td></tr></tbody>"
        rsData.moveNext ' go to next record
        Loop
        strHTML2 = strHTML2 & "</table>"
        searchIT.innerHTML = strHTML2
    end sub
```

**Checkboxes**:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="acheck" onclick="searchdata" id="acheck" checked>
<input type="checkbox" name="ucheck" onclick="searchdata" id="ucheck" checked>
```

**Search input:**

```
<input language="vbscript" onload="searchdata" onkeyup="count2" name="txtsrch" id="searchbar" width="15%" tabindex="0" size="35" type="text">
```

Comment: I suggest you isolate the point where the code raises the error by commenting-out different sections and inserting temporary values for testing.

Comment: I know the full code works without the `If` sections, but then of course the checkbox functions does not work. It seems funny that I get the error because the script `searchdata` is run onload AND when one of the checkboxes are ticked, but the error only occurs when the checkbox is ticked..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out myself. Apparently the function `searchdata` has to be called like `searchdata()`. This solved this problem but brought other problems, which I now have to face :-) Thanks to Smandoli for the suggestions.

**Before**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="acheck" onclick="searchdata" id="acheck" checked>
```

**Solution**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="acheck" onclick="searchdata()" id="acheck" checked>
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters, figure out if the error is raised in your database-engine or VBscript.  To test the first possibility, I'd look at your SQL string:

```
SQL_query = "SELECT * FROM ... WHERE ... Type='" & Chkboxval & "' ..."
Set rsData = conn.Execute(SQL_query)
```

What happens if you set the SQL (instead of using the form)?  There are only three check-box variants, so testing is easy:

```
Chkboxval = "A"
Chkboxval = "U"
Chkboxval = "U' OR Type='A"
```

I pasted them here to point out your approach to filling `Chkboxval` is awkward and I'm wondering if the database-engine is choking.  So, try:

```
SQL_query = "SELECT * FROM arbejde WHERE Title LIKE '%test%' AND Type='A'"
```

If your three variants all work well, then look at the scripting.  This should all be pretty easy to trouble shoot:  Just "hand-code" test values until you find something that runs.  Work from the simple to the complex, isolate the problem.

Comment: I've already done the "hand-code" testing with:
`SELECT * FROM arbejde WHERE Title LIKE '%"& txtsrch.value &"%' AND Type='A' ORDER BY Title`

`SELECT * FROM arbejde WHERE Title LIKE '%"& txtsrch.value &"%' AND Type='U' ORDER BY Title`
`SELECT * FROM arbejde WHERE Title LIKE '%"& txtsrch.value &"%' AND Type='U' OR Type='A' ORDER BY Title`
They all work perfectly, so nothing wrong there.

The script actually works, but comes up with an error, when I tick of the checkbox. Then when I try to search again only the checkbox that is checked is being searched which tells me that the SQL is done right.